# Hyperlink for sharing a url in skype

Tags: html, hyperlink, deep-linking, skype

I have "Share profile" page in my web app.
I want to add a skype option.
I checked the documentation, but all the examples are for starting a chat or a call with a given user.

But I don't want to specify a user, I want to fill in a message which the user will choose who to send it to.
I've seen it in other apps, but I can't remember where, I only know it's possible.

EDIT: to be more precise I am lookinf for the equivalent of the viber forward functionality.

```
<a href="viber://forward?text=my_text">Share via viber</a>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [RTM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuriapireference)

Comment: @mplungjan I've looked in the documentation link you sent me before I asked the question. As I said I only find example for calls and chats with given users, but I want to user to be able to choose from his contact list. I want to only fill the message with the link.